# Starling Font Fallback

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I'm using bitmap fonts to display text.

In case of special characters such as Chinese, I'd like to be able to fall back to system default instead of having all possible characters in the world in the bitmap font.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Starling's TextField does not provide a way to specify fallback fonts. You will need to check which language you are using beforehand and pass in the font name (in your case system default) that you know will work for the current language.

How to embed a font:

```
    [Embed(source="../embeds/fonts/FuturaLTPro-Book.ttf", embedAsCFF="false", fontFamily="FuturaLTPro-Book")]
    public static const Font_FuturaLTPro_Book:Class;

     // create a TextFormat instance and use it instead of your bitmap font
     var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(Font_FuturaLTPro_Book:Class, 18, 0x000000);
```

Comment: is there a font that works for all languages? or a way to specify a system font without embedding it via bitmap fonts?

Comment: I have edited my answer with a way to specify a font without using bitmap fonts. Font that works for all languages will be necessary to Google about it.

Comment: using "_sans" "_serif" or "_typewriter" will set your font to the system's default sans serif or monospace fonts. That will work on all systems, but It will be a dynamic font, not a bitmap font, so you'll pay in performance